# Employer says my position is being dissolved and replaced with another Job Title yet same duties?

Tags: management, position

I am concerned on what to do in this situation. My employer notified me that my current Supervisory position is being dissolved and will now be called a "Team Leader" position. They also said that I must re-apply if I want the job. The job duties are exactly the same as before. What I don't understand is why go through the trouble? Is this an indirect way of demoting me? This has happened twice to me at this current employer and I've been here for 10 years.

Comment: "If I have to reapply for this job, its just as much issue for me to apply for a job elsewhere... bye!"

Comment: Was an explanation given as to why?  Can you add a country tag to this question, as that may impact the accuracy of any answer you get.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this before and it truly sucks.  The company is shaking the tree to see who will fall loose.  Sometimes people get promoted, and other times people get demoted.  Personally, I'd be looking elsewhere after the first time.

Here's a little more depth to it:

> "It is not uncommon for employers to formally ask all or some of their current staff to reapply for a job after a merger or acquisition.
>
> It can also happen when a company is downsizing, layoffs are planned, and there will be a limited number of new positions. In this case, current employees will have to compete for one of the job openings that will be available.
>
> Another reason for asking employees to reapply is that it precludes discrimination issues that could occur if an employer decides to keep some employees and not others during a restructuring. Starting over with rehiring enables the company to give all current employees an opportunity to apply and, in theory, enables the company to keep the best-qualified employees on board."

Source: https://www.thebalance.com/reapplying-for-a-job-after-a-merger-or-restructuring-2061579

Answer (score 2):

It is an indirect way of laying you off (assuming same pay).

They are probably laying off some positions outright and want those people to have a chance at another position.  A person in another job that is going away might be better than you at your job.

If you get the new job title nothing changes (unless the salary changes).

If you don't get the new job you are laid off.

Say it is football and need to cut a safety.  If I have weak back I may cut them and move a safety to back.

Answer (score 1):

To me, it sounds like they are firing you in an indirect way. Is it paying the same as you were making? If so, they can just change your job title without this hassle. It seems to me that they are trying to find a better version of you possibly at a cheaper rate. I would look for another job since it keeps happening, then it will happen again.